# How to configure containerd to use AWS ECR?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ecr, containerd

I can pull images from ECR with docker, but failed to pull images with containerd.

I have configured it(/etc/containerd/config.toml) many times, but it has not been successful so far.

e.g.

```
...
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths."676199840689.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"]
        username = "AWS"
        auth = "auth from .docker/config.json"
...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you find some alternative? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the workaround I was able to do is

- download from ECR via docker cli
- export the image to zip
- import it to containerd

Downside if this is it takes a lot of space so if your image is 10G you will need to have it stored when doing 'docker pull', once for the zip file and once in the containerd.
Hope it helps